# How do you filter by finding documents that don't have a value of `None` in Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So basically I need to get values from a MongoDB collection, and to get those I want to filter out documents that don't include a value of `None`.
My code:

```
collection.find({"variable1": {$ne : None}})
```

I thought maybe the above code would work because I remember seeing it somewhere but it didn't work. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, I figured it out myself. For some reason I had to put the `$ne` in quotation marks. The correct way to do it is:

```
collection.find({"variable1": {"$ne" : None}})
```

I'm not sure why that works but it does and that's what matters.

Comment: It works because this is valid Python syntax and `{$ne: None}` is not.